# React-Redux: Handling multiple changes of the same redux state property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Assume a Redux store has a state property called **number** with an initial value of 0, it also uses a basic dispatch function with a basic action creator, so we can use **changeNumber** to change the value of **number**, and of course this is also handled in the reducer.

Something like this:

```
const CHANGE_NUMBER = "CHANGE_NUMBER";

//action creator
const AC_change_number = function(n) {
  return {type: CHANGE_NUMBER, number: n}
}

//Mapping state and dispatch
const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
  return {number: state.number};
}

const mapDispatchToProps = function(dispatch) {
  return {changeNumber: function(n) {
    dispatch(AC_change_number(n));
  }};
}

const defaultState = {number: 0}
const rootReducer = function(state=defaultState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case CHANGE_NUMBER:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {number: action.number});
      break;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Now lets see we display this number later in the render and add a button with the following onClick function:

```
  handleClick() {
    this.props.changeNumber(this.props.number+1)
    this.props.changeNumber(this.props.number+1)
    this.props.changeNumber(this.props.number+3)
  }
```

the expected behaviour from the flow of code would be an increase of 5 per click, however the increase is 3, which shows that only the last of the statements is executed. I assume all of these actions are performed synchronously and the last statement is performed on a **number** of still 0, so I would need a method for dispatch 2 to wait until 1 is finished, dispatch 3 until 2 is finished etc., what would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Why exactly would you need to change the state in that way, rather than directly calling `this.props.changeNumber(this.props.number+5)`? Are you sure this is not an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: It is very possible this is a XY problem, the problem however arises if we, for example, add a conditional reset of the number before performing the button logic that the reset will not happen, if you are aware of a simpler solution to this problem, that would be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: Try `batch()` https://react-redux.js.org/api/batch